# Why does yarn build throws error in dockerfile

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, nestjs

I am new to docker and I wanted to create image based on node

```
FROM node:16.14.2-alpine
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /app

COPY package.json ./ 
COPY yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile --production

COPY . .
RUN yarn build

CMD ["yarn", "start:prod"]
```

However, after running docker run --tag app:latest and downloading the dependencies, the following error occurs:

```
> [7/7] RUN yarn build:
#11 39.11 yarn run v1.22.18
#11 39.19 $ rimraf dist
#11 39.29 $ nest build
#11 39.30 /bin/sh: nest: not found
#11 39.31 error Command failed with exit code 127.
#11 39.31 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn build]: exit code: 127
```

Please help me why nest is not found

Comment: are you sure that you want to use nestjs's cli in your production environment? here's my Dockerfile for production: https://gist.github.com/micalevisk/9ee47135b22f284dd73de6ea6d5aa864

Answer (score 1):

You're running your `build` step after installing only `production` dependencies. This means you don't have access to `@nestjs/cli`, `typescript`, or any of the `@types/` packages installed. Even if `@nestjs/cli` was installed this would still fail. Your build should be ran before pruning out the development dependencies, whether you do that with a multi-step build process or just using `yarn prune` is up to you.